# .htaccess file I can't make it working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Disclaimer : I dont know anything about URL rewriting**

currently my URL looks like

```
legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties.php?caseid=7 (any number basically)
```

But how can I make it to looks like the following

```
legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/7/
```

I'm trying but not working `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?`

Please dont make things complicated I dont know anything about URL rewriting so please keep it as simple as possible.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/

RewriteRule ^Parties/caseid/([0-9]+)/?$ Parties.php?caseid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: not working The requested URL /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/5 was not found on this server.

Comment: You wrote your want URL as `/public/admin/Parties/caseid/7/` and npw trying  `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/5`, they are not same.

Comment: see updated code, remember it goes in `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/.htaccess`. Also may I know the reason of down vote?

Comment: no nothing same error even i've restarted apache error is, :  The requested URL /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/5/ was not found on this server.

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess? Are there more rules also?

Comment: .htaccess file is saved inside the public folder (where all my other files are suche as parties.php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57172/discussion-between-anubhava-and-usman-sharif-amjad-khan).

Comment: What exactly is the full path of .htaccess file?

Comment: \www\legalHQWithNewAddressTable\legalHQ\public\admin\.htaccess

Comment: ok try updated code now in `\www\legalHQWithNewAddressTable\legalHQ\public\admin\.htaccess`

Comment: Also to avoid very long comment section [click on chat link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57172/discussion-between-anubhava-and-usman-sharif-amjad-khan)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in the `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.php\?caseid=([0-9]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ admin/%1/caseid/%2/?%3 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/caseid/([0-9]+)/ admin/$1.php?caseid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: may i update my question this public/admin/`parties.php` this file would not be the same all the times BTW that code is not working

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan sorry, had a typo, the `+` in the first condition needed to be in the parens

Comment: error again `The requested URL /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/5/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: how should i use the above url though i'm using the following way `http://localhost/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/5/`

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan The whole `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/` was not part of your question. Add the rewrite base and put the htaccess files in the `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/` folder

Comment: still error `The requested URL /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/5 was not found on this server.`

Comment: can you show me how should i be using it like following? `http://localhost/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/5` or `http://localhost/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/caseid/5/`

Comment: it automatically change the url to `http://localhost/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/AccidentDetails/caseid/5/` but it is not working showing this error `The requested URL /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/AccidentDetails/caseid/5/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Where did you put the rules, did you put them in your public folder?

Comment: yeh .htaccess file is inside the public folder